# MySQL; table merge results in equalization of rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to merge multiple tables all sharing the same data structure into one singular table however, it seems as though upon inserting the tables all it is doing is inserting an x amount of rows to equal out with the amount in the source.

Table 1: 20,000 Data Rows

Index Table: 10,000 Data Rows

So if I were to go and insert Table 1 into the Index table using the following:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO 'database1`.`Index` SELECT * FROM
`database1`.`Table1` ;
```

Using the above, it only inserts 10,000 rows of the available 20,000 to equal out.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the other 10,000 are duplicate values and, since you're using `IGNORE` on the `INSERT`, the statement completes without error.

Comment: I assumed that at first, but each of the tables contains scraped URL's unique to each of the respective sites.

Comment: @user1260196 What's the primary key of the `Index` table?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried. REPLACE INTO it's like INSERT but it't replacing by uniq fields.

```
REPLACE INTO  user (id,name) VALUES (12,"John");
#if there is user with id = 12 it wil lreplace it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using INSERT IGNORE, I'm guessing you have 10000 duplicate keys which are being silently thrown away. Didn't you think it odd that you need that?

Depending on your table layout, you'll need some way to rejig your tables to get around the key constraint. E.g., create a new autoincrement key for the table you're inserting into, append the other table, and sort out the duplications somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structures of the tables. Can you show us "show create table ..." on your two tables?

Also, list the feedback you get from the mysql client (e.g., "Records: 100 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0") - that helps pinpoint what happened and why.

If there are values with UNIQUE KEYS in your table, you won't get all the inserts to succeed.